# CMake on Windows : how to find and link different libraries for release and debug

Tags: windows, cmake

I am porting my code from Linux to Windows. On Windows, I need to link to `libqwt.a` in release mode and `libqwtd.a` in debug mode.

```
IF OS==Windows AND CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE==Debug
    I'm trying to have find_library() find libqwtd.a
ELSE
    find libqwt.a
```

But it only finds `libqwt.a`.

Here is the CMake code :

```
include_directories("${QWT_DIR}/include")
set(QWT_LIB_NAME qwt)
if (WIN32)
    message(STATUS "OS=windows")
    if (${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Debug")
        set(QWT_LIB_NAME qwtd)
        set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES "d.a")
        message(STATUS "Build=debug, Qwt lib="${QWT_LIB_NAME})
    endif (${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Debug")
endif (WIN32)
message(STATUS "Searching Qwt lib="${QWT_LIB_NAME})
find_library(LIB_QWT ${QWT_LIB_NAME} PATHS "${QWT_DIR}/lib" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
message(STATUS "LIB_QWT=${LIB_QWT}")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "${LIB_QWT}")
```

And here is the output :

```
QWT_DIR=C:/lib/Qwt-6.1.4
OS=windows
Build=debug, Qwt lib=qwtd
Searching Qwt lib=qwtd
LIB_QWT=C:/lib/Qwt-6.1.4/lib/libqwt.a
```

Comment: Probably, you forgot to clear CACHED value of  `LIB_QWT` variable before re-run `cmake`.

Comment: How do you clear a cached variable ?

Comment: Remove `CMakeCache.txt` file in the build directory.

Comment: Note, that checking `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable works in MinGW generator, but does not work in Visual Studio generator (which is also "Windows"), because this is a *multiconfiguration* generator, and a build type isn't known at configuration stage (when `CMakeLists.txt` is processed by CMake). For multiconfiguration generators approach for have build-type-specific libraries differs.

Comment: You may also consider deleting the single `CACHED` variable with [`unset`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/unset.html), instead of the entire cache. It looks like this: `unset(LIB_QWT CACHED)`.

Answer (score 0):

As Tsyvarev pointed out, I needed to delete `CMakeCache.txt` in the build directory. So now, the code to handle Windows (debug and release) and Linux builds shrinks down to :

```
include_directories("${QWT_DIR}/include")
set(QWT_NAME qwt)
if ( (WIN32) AND (${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Debug") )
    set(QWT_NAME qwtd)
endif ( (WIN32) AND (${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Debug") )

find_library(LIB_QWT ${QWT_NAME} PATHS "${QWT_DIR}/lib" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
message(STATUS "Found LIB_QWT=${LIB_QWT}")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "${LIB_QWT}")
```